# Longest path in a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Any help will be appreciated)

This problem is also known as a long path problem in a graph but I can’t find anything similar on the Internet

**A graph without loops and multiple edges has an even number of vertices 2n, and the degree of each vertex is greater than or equal to n. Prove that the vertices of the graph can be arranged in a circle so that on both sides of each vertex there will be a vertex adjacent to it.**

Answer (score 2):

HINT: [Ore’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem): in effect you’re being asked to show that the graph has a Hamiltonian cycle.